# Vue how to customize global navbar at view level

Tags: vue.js

Im super new to Vue.
i have a Vue-CLI app, which have a navbar and content.
Navbar is common to all pages, but i want to customize in each page whit some additional content.

Example:

Common-> home | about

View home -> home | about | your are in view home

View about -> home | about | your are in view about

**router/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Home from '../views/Home.vue';
import NavBar from '@/components/NavBar.vue';
Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.component('nav-bar', NavBar);

//...
```

**components/navbar.vue**

```
 <template>
  <div>     
    <b-nav-item to="/">home</b-nav-item>
    <b-nav-item to="/about">about</b-nav-item>

    {{customContent}}
 </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'NavBar',
  props: {
    customContent: {
      type: String,
      default: 'default Content',
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
<div id="app">
  <nav-bar />
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <router-view />
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

**views/home.vue**

```
 <template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <image-card :images="images"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
//how can i customize here the navbar by adding for example 'your are in view home'???
</script>
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: You should be able to get the [current route](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-mode) in the component and have something that displays whatever based on that.

Comment: You can also explore Vuex - https://vuex.vuejs.org/ where you could store into a state the page component you have loaded and make the store value provide you that information through a computed map value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways in which you can solve this problem. I'll list two of them.

### 1. Update NavBar by $route

In this approach, the `NavBar` component already contains all of the possible combinations, and will display the relevant portion(s) depending on what `$route` contains.

Here's some pseudo code:

#### navbar.vue

```
<template>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-left>
    APPNAME
  </div>
  <div v-if="name === 'landing'">
    ...
  </div>
  <div v-else-if="name === 'room'">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

#### App.vue

```
<template>
<div id="app">
  <NavBar :name="$route.name"/>
  <main>
    <router-view/>
  </main>
</div>
</template>
```

In this example, the `NavBar` component is very rigid, and doesn't really lend itself to much reuse. However, it does encapsulate all the relevant code relating to the nav bar.

### 2. Extensible NavBar with slots

In this approach, the `NavBar` only provides the bare-minimum to create a nav bar. The rest of the route-specific elements are to be filled in by the views.

#### navbar.vue

```
<template>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-left">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
      APPNAME
    </div>
    <slot name="left"></slot>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-right">
    <slot name="right"></slot>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

#### App.vue

```
<template>
<div id="app">
  <router-view/>
</div>
</template>
```

#### landing.vue

```
<template>
<div>
  <header>
    <NavBar>
      <template slot="right">
        <span>
          <div class="navbar-item">
            <div class="buttons">
              <button class="button" @click="...">Start Watching</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </span>
      </template>
    </NavBar>
  </header>
  <main>
    ...
  </main>
</div>
</template>
```

This approach has a bit of repetition in terms of DOM elements, but gives you an extremely flexible `NavBar` that can be customized by each view.

The approach you want to use depends on what is important to you.
If strict encapsulation is what you want, then you may want to use approach 1, as all of the `NavBar`-related code is contained within a single file.
However, if you believe that there is a potential for reuse, or if you would like all view-related code to live in one place, then it makes sense to use `slots` instead and extend the `NavBar` as required by each view.

Comment: Both dont like at all, i think a mix of them would be great, but anyway it works.i also tried whit named views, but i dont liked. i just want a "placeholder" and then put content here. thanks.

Edit: at the end i discover this: https://portal-vue.linusb.org/ and works for me.

Comment: Sorry. English mistake. I mean, I don't like both answers 100%. Not that I didn't like them at all.Sorry Guru Prasad and TJ Weems

Comment: I used the approach with slots and I like it very much. It works great for colored AppBars, but if I use a background image in the AppBar, it flickers on every route change. So although I use the same bg pic on each page, apparently it is reloaded everytime the AppBar is rendered. Does anyone have an idea how to get rid of the flickering?

Answer (score 0):

I use a breadcrumb to achieve a similar thing. Just an idea but Vue router allows you to add **meta data** to the current route which you always have access to

router.js

```
path: '/add',
name: 'add',
component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "add" */ '../../views/Add.vue'),
meta: {
    breadCrumb: [
        { name: 'Add New' }
    ]
},
```

Notice the meta object attached to the route.. this will be used to describe the current view.

Breadcrumb.vue component

```
<template>
  <div class="breadcrumb">
    <ul class="d-flex m-0 p-0"
      <li
        v-for="(breadcrumb, idx) in breadcrumbList"
        :key="idx">
        {{ breadcrumb.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Breadcrumb',
  data () {
    return {
      breadcrumbList: []
    }
  },
  mounted () { this.updateList() },
  watch: { '$route' () { this.updateList() } },
  methods: {
    routeTo (pRouteTo) {
      if (this.breadcrumbList[pRouteTo].link) this.$router.push(this.breadcrumbList[pRouteTo].link)
    },
    updateList () { this.breadcrumbList = this.$route.meta.breadCrumb },
    formatPath(path) {
      const newPath = path.replace(/\//g, " > ")
      return newPath
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And then you can import the breadcrumb into your navbar or where ever you would like to place it

```
<Breadcrumb class="breadcrumb" />

import Breadcrumb from '@/components/Breadcrumb.vue'

components: {Breadcrumb}
```

So basically the breadcrumb will always watch your current route and change the data based on the meta data you provide in your router.js file

Answer (score 0):

You can access to router name like this:

```
 <div v-if="this.$route.name == 'home'">
        <HeaderTransparent />
 </div>
 <div v-else>
        <HeaderWhite />
 </div>
```

Comment: you shouldn't use `this` within the template but you can access `$route.name` - alternatively add a computed `isHome`